# What is the best way to send the data from Salesforce to the third party on real time?

Tags: apex, integration, force.com, platform-event, third-party

We have multiple objects (contact, account, etc.) for which we want to send the data to a **third party in real-time**, like when any fields value changes at object level that time we want to call third party API and want to send real-time data to the third party and the record count may be in millions.

There may be a case where we are changing thousands of the data/records at a time on the SF side and we need to sync all of those records with a third party.

So can anyone please help me with this that what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) trigger to send out data in very-near-real-time, or you can write an integration on the third-party service (if possible) to listen for CDC events from Salesforce directly.

Comment: Is Change Data Capture is a Package? How can I use  Change Data Capture in SF?

Comment: @Ravi it's a built-in API.